# Connecting to Docker container from host

Tags: mysql, jdbc, docker

I just pulled and run the official [Docker MySQL image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) and have it running locally on my machine:

```
docker run --name mydb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -d mysql:5.7.11
```

The instructions on that screen tell you how to connect to the MySQL server (container) from inside yet another container (which is configured as a command-line client). But I have a generic JDBC fat client ([SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net)) and am wondering how to connect to my docker container.

For the JDBC connection string, I need to provide both a **hostname** and a **dbname**, what can I use? I would imagine the Docker container is somehow addressable from my host OS, but I haven't actually created any databases yet, so I'm not sure what `dbname` value I can supply:

```
jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:3306/<dbname>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run your instance with forwarding 3306:

```
$ docker run --expose=3306 -p 3306 mysql
```

See [incoming ports](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports).

The you specify:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/<dbname>
```

You command become:

```
$ docker run --name mydb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -d --expose=3306 -p 3306 mysql:5.7.11
```

You might need to change the MySQL configuration.

Can go inside the container with:

```
$ docker exec -it mydb bash
```

And then you could:

```
$ echo "bind-address = 0.0.0.0" >> /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Don't forget to reload mysql.

Then you have to create the database and import your schema (if needed).

```
$ mysql -uroot -p12345 -e"CREATE DATABASE mydb"
$ mysql -uroot -p12345 mydb < mydb-schema.sql
```

Comment: Thanks @joksnet (+1) - please see my updated question which now contains the exact Docker command I ran. When I try merging in your `--expose` and `-p` arguments, I get all sorts of errors. **How do I run my command with your (merged) expose/p args?** Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again!!! One quick followup question, if you don't mind: When you say "*Don't forget to reload mysql*", do you mean to stop/restart the container? Thanks again!

Comment: Just try `service mysql reload` from inside the container. ;)